# How would I position a custom launcher icon set on ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How would I position a custom launcher icon set on ActionBar ?
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <application
     android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:icon="@drawable/thca_trans"
     android:label="@string/app_name">
```

I would like it to position it with a left margin to stop it from cutting off the left edge of my icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create a style for your Action Bar Icon.

```
<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBarView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_bg</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
</style>
```

You can add the above code in your styles.xml.
Or if you cannot solve your problem by the above method and want a totally custom action bar of your own, you can even do so. Take a look at this [link](http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android) for that.

Comment: Also added an extra 20 pixels to the width on the left side of the image worked perfectly.

Comment: @StevenHammons, why bother to be complicated, simply create a icon with the content offset

Comment: I was asking for future reference to add padding, margin programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You must create a drawable file containing a "layer-list" like this:

actionbar_logo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/topbar_logo"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:left="10dp" />
</layer-list>
```

In yours activity set:

```
this.getActionBar().setIcon( R.drawable.actionbar_logo);
```